# How can I use a pattern match to get a reference to an f64 value inside an Rc<Enum::Variant(f64)> without cloning?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I am trying to get a value out of a Ref.

The `Ref` contains an enum (FeelValue) which has a variant (Number) that holds an `f64`. FeelValue is not `Copy` and I do not want to clone it. I just want to get a reference to the f64 value so I can perform a comparison with it.

This is what does not work:

```rust
pub enum FeelValue {
  Number(f64),
  Boolean(bool),
  String(String),
  
  // ... many other variants

  Null
}

let a: std::cell::Ref<FeelValue> = ...;
let b: std::cell::Ref<FeelValue> = ...;

match (a,b) {
  (FeelValue::Number(a_number), FeelValue::Number(b_number)) => FeelValue::Boolean(a_number < b_number),
  _ => FeelValue::Null 
}
```

I can't do `match (*a, *b)` because FeelValue is not Copy. I can clone, but I don't want to. (This is the core of a sort routine which already has to clone everything once.)

How do I get that f64 value out of the `Ref<FeelValue::Number>` ?

In case you are curious why I am using a `Ref`, it comes from getting a reference to one value in  an `Rc<RefCell<Vec<T>>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `match (&*a, &*b)`.

The `*` dereferences the `Ref<T>` into the inner value `T` and the `&` just yields a reference to that inner value.

Comment: Another one of those unintuitive Rust idioms. Thanks! Works like a charm.

Comment: @PaulChernoch If `&*` is too magical, note that `match (*a, *b)` also compiles ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3405e9834f3a9baaf1779d3d23dc03bb)), as does `match (a.deref(), b.deref())`, provided you `use std::ops::Deref` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d01ab07ecdb04e6a4f9cfd79485f785)). Being able to omit the `&` in some places is probably the result of the [match ergonomics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md) feature.